# Access Response Object of OData Batch Submit

Tags: javascript, odata

I'm using OData batch submit as below and I'm getting the response for the batch request.

```
oModel.submitChanges({
            groupId: "grpUpdate",
            success: function (oData, Response) {

        });
```

And the response object is like below

[image]

So path to access change responses is

> Response.data.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses[0]

And there are no methods defined to access these private properties.

Is there any other way to access these private properties using methods instead of access the private properties directly?

Comment: there is no other way to access those properties.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question but maybe it'll help someone. I was looking something else and maybe found my answer too.

```js
    success: function (oData, oResponse) {
                        if (oData.__batchResponses) {
                            this.getView().setBusy(false);                      
                            if (oData.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses) {
                                let iNumberOfLines = oData.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses.length;
                                if (iNoOfLines !== 0) {
                                 this._displayMessage(oData.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses);
                                }
                      }.bind(this),
    error: function (oError) {}.bind(this);
```